# Remove all lines that don't end with specific string

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

working on a large text file and I'd like to remove all lines that don't contain the text `"event":"click"}]`

I've tried to do some regex within Sublime 3 and can't get it to stick.

Comment: so what have you tried? If you show some effort, we might be able to point out where you went wrong and better help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used sublime but you could select all line not containing the text `"event":"click"}]` with the regex:

```
^(.(?!"event":"click"\}\]))*$
```

I think you could replace them by nothing(empty string) or backspace

Answer (score 1):

Use this one to get result to stdout

```
sed -n '/"event":"click"\}\]$/p' your_large_file
```

Use this one to keep only lines that end with `"event":"click"}]`, your_large_file.old backup will be generated

```
sed -i.old -n '/"event":"click"\}\]$/p' your_large_file
```